# Scrapy wildcards and multiple classes

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I'm kinda new to web scraping so I figured I should ask here, I can't seem to find an answer or somewhere to look for answers so here it is.

```
response.css("#stream-item-tweet-988415011382091776 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) >p:nth-child(1)::text").extract()
```

This is my current method for extracting text from a tweet.

I need to find a method of wild-carding the `988415011382091776` so that it will pull anything from `#stream-item-tweet-**` and continues with the rest of the line.

If there is something I need to learn please point me in the right direction. Any input would be great.

Comment: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions

Comment: I'd advise to go for xpath, for example: `response.xpath('//*[contains(@id, "stream-item-twet-")]')`

Comment: Try with response.css("//*[@id="stream-item-tweet] > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) >p:nth-child(1)::text").extract()

Comment: Thanks so the command i came up with was : response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-")]').extract()    this gives me the class of the responce now ive just gotta pull the text out of it any ideas?

Comment: How about adding a `/text()` to the xpath? E.g. `response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "some_class")]/text()')`, or it's not the first child, then `//text()`.

Answer (score 0):

The code then ended up giving me all the infomation i needed was.

```
response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-")]/text()').extract()
```

bosnjak was a huge help take you